# SQL how to merge similar records into single row from same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, records

I'm currently trying to clean up a database of mailing subscribers that a former employee created. I've been able to consolidate and fix most issues (primarily duplicates), but I have instances of subscribers with duplicate records because they are subscribed to multiple regions. What I want to do is merge those duplicate records into 1.

Here is an redacted actual example of a duplicate record that I'd like to merge:

```
id     first     last    address    truck    machinery    gl    ne    nw
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Chuck     G....   12 Lorem   1                     1
2      Chuck     G....   12 Lorem            1                        1
3      Chuck     G....   12 Lorem            1                  1
```

And I'd like to merge the 2 into 1 record, and delete all duplicates (some have up to 9 duplicates) like this:

```
id     first     last    address    truck    machinery    gl    ne    nw
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Chuck     G....   12 Lorem   1        1            1     1     1
```

Comment: What IF some rows contain different values in the same column, for example machinery=1,2,3 ? Which  value must be picked ?

Comment: In these cases, itll always only be a '1' or NULL. Its purpose is to simply define whether or not they subscribe to that edition. So if a '1' exists in that column anywhere in the duplicate rows, then '1' should be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Group By` and `Max/Min` Aggregate

```
SELECT id, 
       first, 
       last, 
       address, 
       Max(truck)     AS truck, 
       Max(machinery) AS machinery, 
       Max(gl)        AS gl, 
       Max(ne)        AS ne, 
       Max(nw)        AS nw 
FROM   yourtable 
GROUP  BY id, 
          first, 
          last, 
          address
```

Comment: Brilliant. So simple. Using this kind of selection I was able to make a new list of subscribers without any duplicates, and have all the appropriate data merged.

Comment: how would you approach this when the column is text?